# Camel TypeConverter still throws NoTypeConversionAvailableException even if allowNull set to true in @Converter annotation

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm using **Apache Camel 3.4.3** and trying to convert empty value for my camel route

```
     from(endpointURI)
        .convertBodyTo(DataContainer.class)
        .to(DIRECT_ROUTE)
```

with custom TypeConverter like this:

```
@Converter(allowNull = true)
public DataContainer toDataContainer(String xml) {
    LOGGER.info("Received body as string [{}] try to convert to DataContainer", xml);
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(xml)) {
        return null;
    }
    if (!XmlUtils.isXml(xml)) {
        throw new SwiftCorpException(ErrorCode.ERROR_99999,
            String.format(
                "value [%s] is not a xml, so it cannot be converted to DataContainer",
                xml
            )
        );
    }
    return DataContainer.fromXml(xml);
}
```

but this way fires exception:

> org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException: No body available of type: ru.swiftcorp.common.utils.DataContainer but has value:  of type: java.lang.String on: Message. Caused by: No type converter available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the required type: ru.vtb.swiftcorp.common.utils.DataContainer with value . Exchange[]. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException - No type converter available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the required type: ru.swiftcorp.common.utils.DataContainer with value ]

I started debugging, and found out when *allowNull* in *@Converter* annotation setted to *true*, this leads to the execution of the following code into `CoreTypeConverterRegistry` class inside method `public <T> T mandatoryConvertTo(Class<T> type, Exchange exchange, Object value) throws NoTypeConversionAvailableException`:

```
public <T> T mandatoryConvertTo(Class<T> type, Exchange exchange, Object value) throws NoTypeConversionAvailableException {

    ...
    Object answer = doConvertTo(type, exchange, value, true, false);
    if (answer == null) {
        // Could not find suitable conversion
        throw new NoTypeConversionAvailableException(value, type);
    }
    return (T) answer;
}
```

here's ***answer*** is null and next step NoTypeConversionAvailableException throws.

But Apache Camel says next [(here's a link)](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/type-converter.html#TypeConverter-Returningnullvalues) :

> If null should be allowed as a valid response, then from Camel 2.11.2/2.12 onwards you can specify this in the annotation as shown

So my question is how i can return *null* (and can I do this) value in type converter so that my route does not break in the place where the conversion takes place?

Comment: @Converter(generateLoader = true) is used on class level in documentation, and you use it on method level.

Comment: @Mr_Thorynque, i'm using spring so my converter class looks like this: ``@Component public class DataContainerTypeConverters implements TypeConverters ``

Comment: class annotation @Converter(generteLoader=true) didn't help me

Comment: @BeardlessMonk did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the EXACT issue right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `convertBodyTo` is using mandatory conversion, which means that an exception will be thrown if it was not possible to converter.

You can argue that `allowNull` even for mandatory conversion should be valid. However that was not its original design, as it was for regular conversion (not mandatory). As mandatory is a contract that guarantees that there is always a response object of that given type (its never null).

Also `allowNull` was introduced when you have fallback converters that may or may not be able to convert depending on the content of the input data.

Need to think a bit more about this, whether we should either relax `convertBodyTo` to be non mandatory, or add a flag so you can turn mandatory on|off

Comment: Created a JIRA ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-16913

Comment: So our route doesn't deliberately use `convertBodyTo`, but we still see the issue.  Please see my solution below

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue and ended up doing a `doTry()` and specifically gracefully catching the `NoTypeConversionAvailableException`.

Sample converter:

```java
@Converter(generateLoader = true)
public final class TestConverter {

    @Converter(allowNull = true)
    public static MyObject parse(String message) { 
       if (!StringUtils.hasText(message)) {
         return null;
       }
       MyObject obj = new MyObject();
       obj.setMyFirstProperty(message.substring(10, 11));
       // Set other fields, etc.
       return obj;
    }
}
```

Sample route (automatically uses the `@Converter` from the Camel `TypeConverterRegistry` when using the `generateLoader = true` parameter):

```java
from("direct:test")
    .log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, logger, "${body}")
    .doTry()
        .bean(myService, "processTheMessage")
    .doCatch(NoTypeConversionAvailableException.class)
    .end();
```

It's not my favorite solution since `allowNull` is documented functionality in the Camel documentation, but it allows me to gracefully discard

Comment: This is a good solution, but we went the other way - we check the input message for an empty body at the beginning of the route. I know this is a fairly simple method, but effective.